# Webdriver Chrome selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Estou com o seguinte código:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\libjava\\chromedriver2.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options); // <<< LINHA DO ERRO
```

Retornando o erro abaixo:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.is(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.init(RemoteWebDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:123)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    at webscrapping.WebScrapping.main(WebScrapping.java:36)
```

Alguem poderia ajudar?

Comment: qual versão do Selenium? essa exceção indica que ele ta tentando chamar um método abstrato, aparentemente o do options ali

Comment: Tenho na bibliotecas a  selenium-api-3.8.1.jar  e também a selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar

Answer (score 0):

pode tentar o seguinte:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setHeadless(true);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\libjava\\chromedriver2.exe");
       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```